# How to create npm/yarn dependency tree from just package.json; without creating node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

I inherited an application which works fine in node8, but `npm install` fails in node10, giving an error about `fibers` package being built using node-gyp

`fibers` is not a direct dependency of the app, so I want to know which dependency is bringing in `fibers` as it's dependency.

Unfortunately, `npm ls`, `yarn why` only works when `node_modules` is generated completely through `npm install` or `yarn install`.
I did research online but couldn't find a static dependency tree generator just from package.json.

Even though I could just use node8 and run `npm install` followed by `npm ls` to figure out whose bringing in `fibers`; I believe there should be an easier static analysis of `package.json`.

Is there no way to statically analyze a `package.json` and create a dependency graph for it in npm/nodejs ?

I come from java and we had maven which can just analyze a file named `pom.xml` to create a nice graph about whats coming from where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Execute `npm install` in the directory and let it fail.
2. It'll output something like 
   `A log of this can be found at <location>`
3. Open the log file and search for the text `saveTree`.
4. Notice a hierarchy of resolved packages
5. Here you can find the module you're looking for and whose bringing it in.